# Uses of using Multiple forms in jsf

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, web, primefaces, richfaces

What is the difference between using single(God) form and using multiple forms in single XHTML page in JSF? does this effect while submitting page(POST req). For example what happens when i submit the form containing 10 components in which only two components data has been changed using ajax request(all are in single form) and what happens if i use multiple form in the same scenario? could any one please provide any document or any link that says pros and cons of using multiple forms and single form.Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When you use multiple forms each will have it's own submit button, but only one of them can be sent at a time and also depending on the browser you may loose the data what's in the other forms.

For more information, please refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7182038/using-multiple-forms-or-multiple-submit-buttons-whats-the-difference)

Comment: i don't have submit button in each form, for ex i have 10 components,9 input text components and 1 submit button.if i put 9 input text components in to three different forms ie form1 form2 and form3 whch contains three input text components each,when i click on submit button which is in another separate form,i will process only those which has data, for ex i have put some data in first component in form1, 2nd component in form3, i have not changed anything in 2nd form. what happens in post back request?? and i have 9 components along with submit button in single form if i submit what happens?

Comment: @Karthi Kashav is right, it is not related to submit button in form. Simple example footer of page: footer contains command links and links should be inside form.